# Maui Blazor Android - Open 'AlarmPage' after ExactAlarm Fires

Tags: android, navigation, blazor, alarmmanager, maui

In regards to making an Alarm Clock App using MAUI Blazor Hybrid Android.
I'm really new to this stuff, so please go easy on me :).

I'm trying to display an alarm page to the user, similar to the alarm clock app that comes with most devices.  The problem is after the exact alarm fires, I don't know how to...

1. Start the App if it's not currently running.
2. Navigate or otherwise display the alarm page

This is what I'm using to set the alarm...

```
        public void SetAlarm(int AlarmId, DateTime alarmTime)
        {
            var alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.Instance, typeof(AndroidAlarmService));
            alarmIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.IncludeStoppedPackages);
            alarmIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            alarmIntent.PutExtra(ALARM_ID_KEY, AlarmId);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(MainActivity.Instance, AlarmId, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Mutable);
            var alarmManager = MainActivity.Instance.alarmManager;

            var difference = alarmTime - DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            var differenceAsMillis = difference.TotalMilliseconds;

            //alarm.Time.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
            alarmManager.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis() + (long)differenceAsMillis, pendingIntent);
        }
```

And this is what I'm using to receive the alarm...

```
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, global::Android.Content.Intent intent)
        {
            var getAlarmIdResult = intent.GetIntExtra(ALARM_ID_KEY, 0);
            if (getAlarmIdResult < 1) return;

            //if App is not running, then start App.
            if (MainActivity.Instance == null)
            {
                context.StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            }
            
            //Display Alarm Page for User...
            //[Inject] private NavigationManager uriHelper { get; set; }
            //uriHelper.NavigateTo(AlarmPage);

            Console.WriteLine("ALARM FIRED!");
        }
```

Thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction :)

I've tired using...

`App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync()`

But I have no idea how to convert my ComponentBase into a Page

Comment: Do you want to implement this functionality in a Xamarin Android app or a Maui app? And I found out that your code is Android code.

Comment: Correct, this is all Maui/Xamarin Android Platform code.  My preference (for now) is to implement the 'AlarmPage' page in Maui Blazor.  

But that may not be the best solution; since I'm not familiar enough yet with how Android wants to display a page which does not require user to unlock their device 
i.e. the Alarm page (for most alarm apps) allows users to 'dismiss' without the usual pin / pattern / etc.

Comment: `the Alarm page (for most alarm apps) allows users to 'dismiss' without the usual pin / pattern / etc` Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by above words. Can you elaborate on that, and your specific needs?

Comment: Yeah it's all good mate, I'll post the solution next week when i have more time.